# Alterar cor do Back Button da Toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout

Como eu altero a cor do *Back Button* (ou *Up button*) da minha Toolbar ?
Quando rodo a aplicação ele aparece preto.

Comment: Não é um _back button_ mas sim um _Up button_ , apesar do desenho.

Comment: @PabloAlmeida, porque não alterou o texto para o nome correto?

Comment: @DotNet Porque muita gente deve buscar com esse nome. Provavelmente mais do que com "Up". Mas a ideia é boa. Vou editar pra deixar os dois termos. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fala Vinicius,

É bom você sempre postar o código que está usando, pra evitar ser negativado!

Suponhamos que você está declarando a sua toolbar, dessa forma:

```
Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
```

Então, você consegue alterar a imagem do backbutton, dessa forma:

```
mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_grey600_24dp);
mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Abraços.

Comment: obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que não tenha como mudar a cor dele, e sim usar outra imagem no lugar já que ele é um `drawable`. Para isso crie uma imagem de sua preferência(com a cor que você quer) e adicione na pasta `/drawable` de seu projeto, feito isso basta adicionar essa linha no tema(fica na pasta `/style`) do seu aplicativo:

```
<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/minha_imagem</item>
```